# C# check if tab is opened

Tags: c#, .net, ribbon

I have litle problem in my software. Am using ribbon library and have ribbon toolbar and tabcontrol. On button click i create new tab item.

How to check if tabitem opened? If is opended just select that tab.

*When i click 5x on button i get 5 tabitems opened.*

```
private void buttonItem14_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabItem orderTab = tabControl1.CreateTab("Orders");    

    // Check if tab is opened    
    // etc... ...  
}
```

Any solution to slove this?

Comment: Can you create it once, somewhere else, and hide/show it?

Comment: I can do all that operation but i dont want multiple tabs to open

Comment: What ribbon library are you using? What is the type of `tabControl1`?

Comment: devcomponents is library tabControl is id <name> of component

Comment: @Ikac If you create it once, when your application starts, for example, then merely show or hide it on the button click, will you not achieve what you want?

Comment: WHen i click on button i create new tab item with the some name that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through all the open tabs and compare something that is always different for each tab, the header for example. Here is the code I usually use, it is not optimal but it gets the job done.

```
            if (tabControl.HasItems)
        {
            foreach (TabItem t in tabControl.Items)
            {
                if ((string)t.Header == "Hello")
                {
                    t.IsSelected = true;
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

            tabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem()
            {
                Header = "Hello",
                Content = new UserControl(),
                IsSelected = true
            });
```

First we check if there are any tabs in the tab control, if not we go on and create it. If there are we compare the header of each item to the header of the tab we want to prevent from opening again. If there is a match we just switch to the tab and exit the method if not the code for creating it is executed following the flow of the program. UserControl() Is the class from which I get the content for my tab you can ignore it.